# Prove or disprove that the sum of two irrational numbers is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove or disprove that the sum of two irrational numbers is irrational. How do i answer this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you any thoughts of your own on this problem?

Comment: I don't know how to define an irrational number, root a doesn't work and i can't think of another way

Comment: Well understanding the definitions is really the beginning of how to work with these questions, and questions such as this are asked to help you to think through what the definitions imply. So you need to make sure you do know the definition.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask: Given $a, b \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q, a \ne -b$, does $a + b \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q $ ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions, but I can't find them. Oh well, it's also missing context, so I will close it as that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $-\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} = 0$, so the sum of two irrationals may be rational.

Comment: How is that the sum though, isn't that the difference? Isn't it the same as saying root 2 - root 2?

Comment: a sum takes the form $a_{1}+a_{2} + \cdots$...

Comment: So does that prove or disprove the question? It says the sum of two irrational numbers is irrational, but can't it be both rational and irrational?

Comment: What do you think "irrational" means, @Heelloppp ?

Comment: It disproves the proposition.

Comment: It's like asking if a woman can both be pregnant and not pregnant…

Comment: @Heelloppp: A real number that is not rational is called irrational. Very simple, please be noted.

Comment: @Heelloppp $\sqrt 2+(-\sqrt 2)=0$ and you will admit that $-\sqrt 2$ is irrational, I think.

Answer (score 3):

($2+\sqrt3$)+($2- \sqrt3$) $=$ $4$  which  is  rational. So , the  statement " sum of two irrationals is irrational"  is  disproved since  counter example  is  found.

When  a  statement  like  that  is  given  to   prove  or  disprove, " sum of two irrationals is irrational" , it  is  proved  if  it  is found  to  be  always true  and  disproved  if  at  least  one   counter  example  can  be  given.

In  fact,  sum  of  two  irrationals  can  be  either  rational  or  irrational. Not  necessarily  irrational  all  the  time.